# VBA Error: Run-time error '1004' on pasting values to a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste some values between worksheets using VBA. I don't see anything inherently wrong with my code but I keep getting the above error.

```
Set fullCopyRange = ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRowRow + 1, 8))
fullCopyRange.Copy_ Destination:=Sheets("Requirements").Range(Cells(pasteDestinationLastRowRow + 1, 2))
```

The first line executes fine, the second does not. `pasteDestinationLastRowRow`, I can check beforehand, does indeed have a non empty value, and yet this still returns an error and I have no idea why.

Comment: fullCopyRange.Copy_  ? change for fullCopyRange.Copy

Answer (score 1):

Replace your lines as follows:

```
Set fullCopyRange = Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(lastRowRow + 1, 8))
fullCopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Requirements").Cells(pasteDestinationLastRowRow + 1, 2)
```

and try again.

We qualify the `Cells()` in the first line and fix the syntax in the second.